# How to find server on LAN with sockets (UDP) in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, connection

Hello fellow programmers! I am writing a program in C++ that is supposed to allow for real time data transfer between 2 computers over LAN using windows sockets. Since the data is supposed to be transferred as fast as possible I use UDP (this is a game, therefore only the newest data is relevant). Now, since I tested it on single machine i use the following code to assign server IP to the client

```
SOCKADDR_IN server_address;
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_address.sin_port = htons(PORT);
server_address.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1 = 127;
server_address.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2 = 0;
server_address.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3 = 0;
server_address.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4 = 1;
```

Now, I need it to run within LAN where the exact addresses of server and client may be unknown. How to connect in such a case? Is it enough if I broadcast to 255.255.255.255? Or maybe there is another way of handshaking 2 computers?

Comment: You could have a separate broadcast-phase where the client sends a broadcast to the network. The server watch for those and replies with its own address. A limitation is that broadcasts might not be passed between segments of the network with the same network-mask. To overcome that you could have a directory" server at a fixed and well-known address where clients can connect and get a list of known servers. Or just have the users type in the address of the server each session.

Comment: Well, you can certainly send a datagram to the broadcast IP address. And then hope that only one IP address responds. What if you get two replies? Or four? Our 42? What do you propose to do next? If you're planning to only process the first response to the broadcast, how do you make sure that your intended IP address always responds first?

Comment: You might want to look at using an IP multicast announce/discover mechanism such as [avahi](https://www.avahi.org/).

Comment: It is enough for me to respond to the first broadcast only. Also, I imagine I could send 1 packet of data with a number that both server and client will have, if the number does not match i can disconnect the socket.

Comment: Can two different people play two different games at the same time?

Comment: @user253751 No, I can rule out such an option. I will assume that in the LAN there will be only 1 server and 1 client and no other processes that will respond to my broadcast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i finished my project, so I will take the opportunity to show a code I used for finding a server. As suggested, it is based on broadcasting on client side and sending a datagram back, providing server's IP to the client, which is used later to provide directed communication later on.

SERVER:

```
bool handshakeS()
{
    SOCKET sockhs;
    sockhs = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    char broadcast = '1';
    if (setsockopt(sockhs, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast, sizeof(broadcast)) < 0)
    {
        closesocket(sockhs);
        return false;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in Recv_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in Sender_addr;

    int len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    char recvbuff[1];
    int recvbufflen = 1;
    char sendMSG[] = "";

    Recv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    Recv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORTHS);
    Recv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(sockhs, (sockaddr*)&Recv_addr, sizeof(Recv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        closesocket(sockhs);
        return false;
    }
    recvfrom(sockhs, recvbuff, recvbufflen, 0, (sockaddr*)&Sender_addr, &len);

    if (sendto(sockhs, sendMSG, strlen(sendMSG) + 1, 0, (sockaddr*)&Sender_addr, sizeof(Sender_addr)) < 0)
    {
        closesocket(sockhs);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    closesocket(sockhs);
}
```

CLIENT:

```
bool handshakeC(int& ip1temp, int& ip2temp, int& ip3temp, int& ip4temp)
{
    SOCKET sockhs;
    sockhs = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    char broadcast = '1';
    if (setsockopt(sockhs, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast, sizeof(broadcast)) < 0)
    {
        closesocket(sockhs);
        return false;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in Recv_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in Sender_addr;

    int len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    char sendMSG[] = ""; //may be used for authorization
    char recvbuff[1] = "";
    int recvbufflen = 1;

    Recv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    Recv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORTHS);
    Recv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_BROADCAST;

    sendto(sockhs, sendMSG, strlen(sendMSG) + 1, 0, (sockaddr*)&Recv_addr, sizeof(Recv_addr));
    recvfrom(sockhs, recvbuff, recvbufflen, 0, (sockaddr*)&Recv_addr, &len);

    ip1temp = Recv_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1;
    ip2temp = Recv_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2;
    ip3temp = Recv_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3;
    ip4temp = Recv_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4;
    closesocket(sockhs);
    return true;
}
```